# Understanding of Archimedean Property

Tags: analysis

*Archimedean Property*.For any $x,\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \varepsilon>x$.

Proof. If $x\leq 0$ then pick $n=1$. The interesting case is that $x>0$.

Let $A=\left\{n \varepsilon :n\in \mathbb{N} \right\}$. Suppose that $n\varepsilon\leq x$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $x$ is upperbound for $A$. Obviously $A$ is not empty. Thus, by the Dedekind axiom, it has supremum, say $s$. Then $s-\varepsilon$ is not an upperbound for $A$ as $s-\varepsilon<s$. **So, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\varepsilon>s-\varepsilon$** and hence $n\varepsilon+\varepsilon>s$. But $n\varepsilon+\varepsilon=\varepsilon \left( n+1\right)$ and this element is in $A$. Therefore, $s$ cannot be an upperbound for $A$.

**My question is** the sentence of ''so, there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\varepsilon>s-\varepsilon$''. Why there is, how do we know? Can you explain?

Comment: A real number $x$ is **not an upper bound of A** if there exists at least one $y \in A$ such that $y > x$.

Comment: @LearningMathematics noope.

Comment: can you explain why this is false?

Comment: @LearningMathematics Because I said that ''for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$'', $n\varepsilon<x$. So, by the definition of upper bound, $x$ is an upper bound for $A$.

Comment: I'm saying just the meaning of "not an upper bound". That is, $s-\epsilon$ is not an upperbound of $A$ implies there exist at leas one member $y \in A$ such that $y> s-\epsilon$. In case your $y=n\epsilon$

Comment: @LearningMathematics ha yes. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If there were no such element $n\in\mathbb N$, then $s-\epsilon$ would be a supremum of $A$ that is strictly smaller than $s$. This is a contradiction by uniqueness of suprema.